# Sorting arrays in parallel

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a hash as follows:

```
{
  :student_name => ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  :total_marks => [100, 25, 50]
}
```

I want to sort each value (array) of this hash by the order of the corresponding element in the value for `:total_marks` when this array is sorted. The resultant hash should look like this:

```
{
  :student_name => ['B', 'C', 'A'],
  :total_marks => [25, 50, 100]
}
```

What is a scalable solution? This hash can have many other attributes.

Comment: Your expected hash is invalid.

Comment: One suggestion I'd like to make is to hold your data together, rather than as two parallel arrays. Otherwise, it might be difficult to achieve the scalability you want because one routine will have to first sort your `:total_marks` array and perform the same set of steps on the `:student_name` array afterwards. See `Struct` in the ruby docs on how to do that succinctly

Comment: You should remove the Rails tag.

Comment: If you need  a scalable solution I would also think about a solution in a database.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the code to be simple and involve the least amount of indirection, I'd recommend holding the student's name and total mark together, rather than as parallel arrays. This way, you can add extra fields without then having to rewrite your sort routine (which would otherwise have to now resort *another* parallel array for the new field).

```
ExamResult = Stuct.new(:student_name, :total_mark)

exam_results = [
    ExamResult.new('Adam', '25'),
    ExamResult.new('Sajani', '100'),
    ExamResult.new('Sawa', '50')
]

# Sort
exam_results.sort_by &:total_mark
```

As for scalability, that will *heavily* depend on what *kind* of scalability you need. The above method will likely handle hundreds of thousands of `ExamResult`'s without much effort. If you want to do *millions* upon *millions* or exam results without overloading your memory then you're going to need a better way of sorting the grades and streaming exam results anyway, regardless of how you've structured it.

Comment: My code can have extra fields without being rewritten. Although, I agree with you that the OP has bad structure.

Comment: If the OP needs to handle millions, then using a database and handling the sorting inside the database would be appropriate. There's nothing more fun than seeing code spend a while loading millions of records then crashing. Also, it's not necessary to say "EDIT" and "EDIT2". We can tell what was edited and when it occurred. Instead, modify the document as necessary to maintain cohesive and intelligible content.

Comment: `sort_by` isn't just cleaner, it's usually a lot faster. `sort` will repeatedly compute the intermediate values used for comparison, whereas `sort_by` will remember them. There are times that `sort` results in a faster sorting algorithm depending on what's being sorted, so benchmarking is important.

Answer (score 4):

```
h = {:student_name=>["A", "B", "C"], :total_marks=>[100, 25, 50]}

indices = h[:total_marks].to_enum.with_index.sort_by(&:first).map(&:last)
h.each{|_, v| v.replace(v.values_at(*indices))}
#=> {:student_name=>["B", "C", "A"], :total_marks=>[25, 50, 100]}
```

Comment: Probably the most straightforward solution to OP's question. But, just to illustrate my comment on the original post, this solution requires creating a value, original_index tuple, sorting by the value, keeping the (now re-sorted) original_indexes and using the indexes to re-sort the grade array. EDIT: if the OP just had a properly formatted data structure in the first place we wouldn't need the overhead (is the point I'm making)

Answer (score 1):

Given the design of your hash, we need to first pair student and marks together.

```
h = {
    :student_name => ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    :total_marks => [100, 25, 50]
}

student_array = h[:student_name]
marks_array = h[:total_marks]

student_marks = []
student_array.each_with_index {|student, idx| student_marks << [student, marks_array[idx]]}
p student_marks  # Prints [["A", 100], ["B", 25], ["C", 50]]
```

So, now that we have a array where student and marks are paired, we will sort the above array using second element of sub-array

```
sorted = student_marks.sort {|i, j| i[1] <=> j[1]}
p sorted # Prints [["B", 25], ["C", 50], ["A", 100]]
```

Now that we have sorted student and marks, we will use it to update the original hash with sorted values

```
h[:student_name] = sorted.collect {|i| i[0]}
h[:total_marks]= sorted.collect {|i| i[1]}
p h
```

Finally, we have the result

```
{:student_name=>["B", "C", "A"], :total_marks=>[25, 50, 100]}
```

PS: Look at [sawa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166359/ruby-sorting-array-of-each-attribute-of-a-hashmap-wrt-one-attribute-of-the-has/32166420#32166420) for compact & elegant way of solving this.

Answer (score 0):

```
marks, names = [h[:total_marks], h[:student_name]].transpose.
  sort_by(&:first).transpose
  #=> [[25, 50, 100], ["B", "C", "A"]] 
{ student_name: names, total_marks: marks }
  #=> {:student_name=>["B", "C", "A"], :total_marks=>[25, 50, 100]}
```

The steps:

```
a = [h[:total_marks], h[:student_name]]
  #=> [[100, 25, 50], ["A", "B", "C"]] 
b = a.transpose
  #=> [[100, "A"], [25, "B"], [50, "C"]] 
c = b.sort_by(&:first)
  #=> [[25, "B"], [50, "C"], [100, "A"]] 
d = c.transpose
  #=> [[25, 50, 100], ["B", "C", "A"]] 
marks, names = d
  #=> [[25, 50, 100], ["B", "C", "A"]] 
marks
  #=> [25, 50, 100] 
names
  #=> ["B", "C", "A"] 
{ student_name: names, total_marks: marks }
  #=> {:student_name=>["B", "C", "A"], :total_marks=>[25, 50, 100]}
```

Note that the two arrays transposed are 2xN and Nx2, where N is the number of students. Those arrays will require little memory and transposing them will be very fast compared to the sorting operation, except possibly for one-room schoolhouses.

I initially used `sort` rather than `sort_by(&:first)`, but changed to the latter after reading @theTinMan's comment on @Adam's answer, and then running this simple benchmark:

```
require 'fruity'

n = 100_000
m = (0..10_000).to_a
a = Array.new(n) { [m.sample, m.sample] }    

compare do
  sort    { a.sort }
  sort_by { a.sort_by(&:first) }
end

Running each test once. Test will take about 11 seconds.
sort_by is faster than sort by 5x ± 1.0 (results differ: [[0, 9243], [0, 3145],...
```

As indicated, `sort` and `sort_by(&:first)` do not have the same return values.  When comparing pairs of tuples using `sort`, the second elements of the tuples are tie-breakers when the first elements are equal, whereas `sort_by(&:first)` has no tie-breaker.